# Iterator based version of quicksort, allowing user defined pivot-selection-strategy

Tags: c++, quick-sort

I have implemented a iterator based version of Quicksort, which allows the user to define and pass his own pivot-selection-strategy:

```
template<typename It>
It Partition(It begin,It end,It pivot)
{
    std::swap(*begin, *pivot); 
    pivot = begin;
    It i{ begin }, j = std::next(begin, 1);
    for(;j != end; j++)
    {
        if(*j < *pivot)
            std::swap(*j, *++i);
    }
    std::swap(*pivot, *i);
    return i;
}

template<typename It, typename Pivot>
void Quicksort(It begin, It end, Pivot&& GetPivot)
{
    if (std::distance(begin, end) == 0)
        return;
    It pivot{ GetPivot(begin,end) };
    It elementAtCorrectPosition = Partition(begin, end,pivot);
    Quicksort(begin, elementAtCorrectPosition, GetPivot);
    Quicksort(std::next(elementAtCorrectPosition, 1), end, GetPivot);
}
```

The algorithm can be used in the following way:

```
std::vector<int> v{  3, 8, 2, 5, 1, 4, 7, 6 };
auto quickSort = v;
auto stdSort = v;
Quicksort(quickSort.begin(),
          quickSort.end(),
          [](auto a, auto b) { return a; });
std::sort(stdSort.begin(), stdSort.end());
Assert::IsTrue(quickSort == stdSort);
```

Where the lambda expression

```
 [](auto a, auto b) { return a; }
```

is just to demonstrate how a pivot selection strategy can be passed to the algorithm.

Any suggestions that lead to a more robust, concise and readable code are welcome.

Special thanks to @ratchet freak, who discovered an emberassing bug:

The initial implementation only worked for the special case, where the first element is selected as pivot. See above for the corrected version.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need to `swap(*begin, *pivot); pivot = begin;` at the start of partition. Otherwise the pivot could move.

Comment: Why are you not using [`std::partition`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition)?

Comment: "Why are you not using std::partition"

For practicing purposes...

Comment: @ratchetfreak: You are absolutely right . my initial version only worked for the special case, where the first element is selected as pivot. Thats what happens, if tests are not randomized :-) See the updated op, which includes the corrected version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing that is missing is selecting a custom comparison function. This is usually done by adding a `std::less` like type to the template and passing that on to the partition

```
template<typename It, typename Compare>
It Partition(It begin,It end,It pivot, Compare comp)
{
    std::swap(*begin, *pivot); 
    pivot = begin;  
    It i{ begin }, j = std::next(begin, 1);
    for(;j != end; j++)
    {
        if(comp(*j, *pivot))
            std::swap(*j, *++i);
    }
    std::swap(*pivot, *i);
    return i;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't `Compare` deserve a default like `std::less` also then?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, not in partition as it's an internal util function, but for the sort you could make it a default or add an overload.

Comment: Sure, that was what I meant. Didn't spot that clearly.