# Multidimensional Array indexed by integer array

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, array

I am in need of a multidimensional array that can be initialized easily with arbitrary dimensions. I have found this code [here](http://cpptruths.blogspot.co.at/2011/10/multi-dimensional-arrays-in-c11.html), which is beautiful, however poses some difficulties for me. its hard to initialize with arbitrary size and also difficult to access since I have to input each index using a comma to seperate it.

In my application each array 'slot' has the same size. Furthermore it would be easy to work with, if I could index and access everything using an array, instead of having to input every index seperated by a comma. So I wrote the following code which provides something like that, however feels very heavy due to only using one large array. I am basically shifting the 'multidimensional' array layers into one huge array... abusing high valued indices. Is there a way to approve apon the code, making it faster, and using less memory and high value calculations?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <array>

using namespace std;


template <class T, size_t depth, size_t each_size>
class MultiArray
{
    array<T, static_cast<size_t>( pow(each_size, depth) )> multiArray;

public:
    MultiArray()
    { ; }

    void put(array<size_t, depth> indices, T thing_to_put)
    {
        size_t index = 0;
        int dimension_counter = 0;
        for (const size_t& i : indices)
        {
                index += i * nearbyint(pow(each_size, dimension_counter));
                dimension_counter++;
        }

        this->multiArray[index] = thing_to_put;
    }

    void get(array<size_t, depth> indices, T &thing_to_get)
    {
        size_t index = 0;
        int dimension_counter = 0;
        for (const size_t& i : indices)
        {
                index += i * nearbyint(pow(each_size, dimension_counter));
                dimension_counter++;
        }
        thing_to_get = this->multiArray[index];
    }
};
```

if you would like you can find a slightly longer version of the code above with some debugging, simple testing and very basic error handling [here](http://cpp.sh/9pz4m).

EDIT: I would like to find a very fast and efficiant way to do things! I would be happy about input on how to get a fast multidimensional array class :) Thank you all for your help!!!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to call `pow()` and calculate powers "from scratch" within each loop iteration - it's probably cheaper to multiply the value calculated during previous iteration as you are calculating consecutive powers of `each_size`:

```
size_t temp = 1;
for (const size_t& i : indices)
{
    temp *= each_size;
    index += i * temp;
}
```

Maybe also come up with a better name for this `temp` variable than I did ;p

`std::nearbyint()` is also redunant since you are calculating integral powers of an integer, so your result is going to be an integer by definition.

Apart from this, if your array is really huge, consider using some other container that doesn't store data contiguously as with the fragmented memory there is a risk of not being able to allocate space for such a large object. `std::deque` might fit your needs, but it's certainly less efficient, so you have to weigh pros and cons. Another advantage would be dynamic size that adds more flexibility to the way your array is used (you can also get it with `std::vector`, but it's also a contiguous container).

Last but not least, there is no advantage to passing primitive types such as `size_t` by reference as the associated pointer that's copied is of similar size to the variable that would be copied by value.

Comment: Additionally there is usually no need for using 'const &' with built in types e.g. 'size_t' in this case

Comment: I think that the last point depends on the platform. Usual gaming rigs these days have minimum of 8 GB, and they are slowly moving towards DDR4. Adding upcoming battle of Intel and AMD, I believe innovation will only increase.

Comment: Of course, that's why I mentioned weighing pros and cons. Everything depends on your application and who is your target user. For example for my daily routine 16 GB is often barely enough.

Comment: @Harald Scheirich Thanks for pointing that out, updated my answer.

Comment: The `const size_t&` is fine, and it's different to specifying such a reference in the prototype of a (non-inlined) function - any decent compiler can see the entire scope of `i` and hold it in a register, whether it's passed by reference or by value.  That said, omitting the `&` makes it slightly easier to read.

Comment: thank you very much! the power computiation is very nice! I will try my best naming the thing haha

Comment: No problem - always glad to help ;) @TobySpeight Probably you're right, that's why I've written that there is simply no advantage to doing it, not that doing so has some serious adverse effects.

Answer (score 2):

### pow is not constexpr

pow is not constexpr, and the current behavior relies on particular compiler. You'll need constexpr function to calculate the power.

### Potentially dangerous implementation

Users of the class will need to store the `MultiArray` on free store to ensure they don't overflow the stack (I know some compilers extend it during runtime, but it is still non-standard). I recommend using vector instead.

### Interface

When using `std::vector`, need for templated size arguments disappears. It would be possible to templatize on allocator instead, defaulting to `std::allocator<T>`. The sizes could be passed on constructor call.

### Subscript operator

That's going to be an issue, but it is easily solvable. Just make it

```
T& operator[](const std::initializer_list<std::size_t> indices)
{
    //use math to calculate the index
}
```

You'll also need `const` version. Input type may be different, but it should also check if the number of elements inside match the dimension count. You could templatize sizes still, so that this one can be replaced with `const std::array<std::size_t, DimensionCount>&`.

Comment: thank you very much for you input! I put in your changes, please find the code here cpp.sh/6ngw2  
I ran into some trouble: how can I put the new power function into my class (so everything stays one nice package?) 

Also could you please expand a little on the problem using array? also isn't the template the faster way to do things?

Comment: continuing on my program, I now see the problem with using std::array here! especially when I don't know the size of MultiArray during runtime! thank you again for the input! How could I measure the performance gap between using std:array or std:verctor here?

Comment: Use google benchmark. Or you could try to use  [my solution](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/158074/c-benchmark-v2), but I'm unsure if it has dependencies to my library and in general it is a half baked solution compared to google benchmark. I recommend using google benchmark. About `constexpr pow()`: I don't think it should come with the class, because it is a good, useful standalone function.

Comment: And about templates: it doesn't matter. Having greater performance is side effect. The ultimate things that matter are generated assembly and current load on machine(s). Just benchmark, don't rely on intuition.

Comment: hm not having 'depth' in the template makes passing the indices as std::array impossible, right? should I also use a vector for that?

Comment: @the.polo, the array as index argument requires all of the parameters as they are present in the original question. I'm a bit out of my comfort zone these days, so I'm afraid some of my suggestions might miss the point. Please take with the grain of salt.

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting approach. It has nice sides, because as all dimensions are equally sized, everything is given with only 2 parameters. But it has downsides:

- all dimensions must be equal and known at compile time
- no easy way (at least not currently implemented) to see for example a 3D array as an array of 2D arrays.

For the second point, if you could add an `operator []` that give a *view* on a `MultiArray` having one dimension less and same sizes, you could easily use it with a standard array interface. Still to implement: a `MultiArrayView` class and the `operator[]` on both classes.